# MySQL select some values (not all values) from column of one table and depending on the selected values sum values in other table

Tags: mysql

First table (named `18_8_ChartOfAccounts`) with account numbers like this

```
AccountNumber | VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover
--------------------------------------------------
 1            |    not_blank
 2            |
 3            |    not_blank
```

Second table (named `2_1_journal`) like this

```
Amount | DebitAccount
----------------------
5     |  1
80    |  2
3     |  3
4     |  1
20    |  3
```

Trying to get following: if `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` is not empty/not blank, sum `Amount` where `DebitAccount` is the same as (equal to) `AccountNumber`.

Or want to get output like this:

```
Account number | Total
---------------------------
1              | 9 (5+4)
3              | 23 (20+3)
```

Do not need to echo Total for account `2`, because for account `2` `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` is blank/empty

This mysql query selects **all** `AccountNumber`s from first table (`18_8_ChartOfAccounts`)

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DebitAccount, SUM( Amount ) AS Amount 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
GROUP BY DebitAccount ) 
d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)
```

But need to select only `AccountNumber`s where `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` is not blank/empty

Trying to modify mysql query

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts AS a 

WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover <> ''

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DebitAccount, SUM( Amount ) AS Amount 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
GROUP BY DebitAccount ) 
d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)
```

Get `Syntax error or access violation: ... near 'LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DebitAccount ....`

Then changed `FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts AS a WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover <> ''`

to `FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover <> '' AS a` and get similar error.

Then changed to such code:

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DebitAccount, SUM( Amount ) AS Amount 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
WHERE a.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover <> "" 
GROUP BY DebitAccount ) 
d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)
```

and get `Unknown column 'a.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover'`

Ok in table `2_1_journal` no such column. Want to use `a.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` in the same way as `a.AccountNumber` (both columns are only in `18_8_ChartOfAccounts`. `a.AccountNumber` works, `a.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover` not.

Please, advice what need to modify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work;

```
SELECT AccountNumber, 
       CONCAT(SUM(Amount), ' (', GROUP_CONCAT(Amount SEPARATOR '+'), ')') Total
FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts
LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal
  ON AccountNumber = DebitAccount
WHERE VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY AccountNumber
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91531/7).

Of course, if the sum details was just an example, you can skip the `GROUP_CONCAT()` part and just use...

```
SELECT AccountNumber, COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0) Total
...
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860d09/2).

Comment: Yes, sum details was just as example (excuse me)

Comment: Instead of `<> ''` is `IS NOT NULL`. May any problems if use `<> ''`?

Comment: @user2465936 `<> ''` works well for checking against an empty string, or you may want `VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover IS NOT NULL AND VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover <> ''` in case they can be either. An empty string ('') is not the same as `NULL` (except in Oracle), so they're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Use this query:

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, SUM( b.Amount ) AS Amount
  FROM 18_8_ChartOfAccounts AS a 
     LEFT JOIN 2_1_journal AS b ON a.AccountNumber = b.DebitAccount
        WHERE a.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY b.DebitAccount;
```

Comment: I don't think you really mean to group by a column on the right side of a left join. [It will group all accounts without debits into a single, grouped by NULL, row](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fa057/1).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Its working fine and you have done the group by on the basis on `AccountNumber`, I exclaimed that what you want which column has already unique then what is the mean of doing the group by.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what you are talking, there is no accountNumber 4 and 5. then how it will show. :)

Comment: In the SQLfiddle link in the first comment on your answer (3 comments up), there is. My comment was just that there's a difference between the groupings if accounts have no debits.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
ca.AccountNumber,
sum(j.Amount)
from
18_8_ChartOfAccounts ca
left join 2_1_journal j on ca.AccountNumber = j.DebitAccount
where 
ca.VatReturnRowNumberForDebitTurnover is not null
group by ca.AccountNumber
```

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df31c/3/0).